# Do you have any idea how condescending THAT JUST WAS(tense/phrase)

Tags: phrase-meaning, tense

Let's say there is a *teacher* discussing something negative about farmers to students. One of the students *reacted instantly*, because his parents are farmers, and he said:

> Student: Do you have any idea how condescending **that just was!** (this happened right after his teacher finished the sentence).

Does the bold letters exist, to mean something that has just happened?

Comment: I think either the student was distracted, and didn't frame his utterance well, or (far more likely, imho) he's not a native Anglophone anyway. I can imagine the possibility of ***...how condescending that was just now***, but even that sounds pretty "awkward" to me. In the actual version as cited, ***just*** seems completely out of place. It's not a natural way of conveying ***only a short time ago***, nor is it a natural context for using ***just*** as an "intensifier", as in utterances such as *It's **just** like him to post a comment instead of a proper answer.*

Comment: If I re-construct it to ''do you have any idea how condescending **that is just was''** (-does this exist?) how's that?

Comment: I don't know what you want the word ***just*** to mean in this context. The only idiomatic way I can think of to include it is *Do you have any idea **just how condescending** that was?* (where it's an "intensifier" for "how condescending", implying ***very** condescending*). But you seem to be saying you're interested in using it as per *I just saw him* (meaning ***just a moment ago, very recently***), and I don't think that would be easily done in your context.

Comment: Maybe *Do you have any idea how condescending **you were just now**?* I don't know why, but I like it much better when ***just now*** (= a moment ago) applies to something a bit more specific than just ***that*** (= whatever the teacher just did/said)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, 'just' here indicates something that just happened a moment ago, because 'just' precedes the past tense verb 'was':

> Do you have any idea how condescending that was? (any time in the past)
>   
>  Do you have any idea how condescending that **just** was? (just a moment ago in the past)

To use 'just' as an intensifier to indicate that something was very condescending, it should precede 'how':

> Do you have any idea **just** how condescending that was? (implying that it was very condescending)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the meaning "only a moment ago", *just* may play the role of intensifier as it does in your sentence, meaning that the teacher's attitude was *very* patronizing.